# Why I can't import urllib2? I already have new a python interpreter in preference

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2

```
import urllib2
```

I can't import urllib2. I received this error:

```
Unresolved import: urllib2
```

They said that I should have a new python interpreter in the preference.
But I've already done that. Please give me some clue about this.

Comment: Which operating system and python version?

Comment: windows xp and python 3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python3, you have to use `urllib3`. Documentation http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('GET', 'http://www.google.com')
print (response.data)
```

And there is no `raw_input` in python3. You have to use `input` function in python 3. Python 2's `input` is equivalent to `eval(input())` in python 3

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.x is not compatible with Python 2.x.  Your Internet example is for 2.x, and 3.x does not have an `urllib2` module.

Comment: What it should import in 3.x if I want to use 'raw_input' function?Could you give some suggestion?